in Unity 2022.3, why do my object instantiation times spike ever so often?
So I'm currently creating a game with procedural world generation. Therefore I am loading and unloading big chunks of world data quite often. The process goes as follows:
Step 1: Upon loading a chunk, it gets a thread worker which reads its data from a file in a seperate thread.
This worker also prepares "proto-objects" that contain most of the data that is necessary to instantiate my GameObjects later. This includes things like a Color array to set a texture and a Vector2 array to set a collider.
Step 2: Once the thread is done, it puts the finished proto-objects into a ConcurrentQueue where they are dequeued in the main thread and used to initialize the GameObjects. This includes adding the script and a SpriteRenderer as components and initializing a Texture2D with the createUninitialized flag set to true.
Step 3: The Creation of the collider as well as the application of the Color array to the texture and subsequent Apply() call are handled later (which works fine and is outside of the scope of this post)
Now heres the problem:
Step 2 usually takes about 0.5-5ms.

But every so often it spikes to taking 50-200ms.

As you can see, this happens in more or less regular intervals. I first suspected the garbage collector clears to have something to do with it because you can see it lining up with this spike here. This does not seem to be the case with the others though ...
Also it seems to be texture size independent because in both cases highlighted here, the texture has a size of 160x160, which is the case most of the time...
Anyways, here's the code that gets profiled in the highlighted "Create Objects" part:
public static PhixelObject Create(Chunk chunk, Vector3Int chunkPos, List<Vector2> verticies, List<Phixel> perimeterPhixels, Phixel[,] phixelMatrix, GameObject gameObject = null)
{
    //Create create
    PhixelObject phixelObject = Create<PhixelObject>(gameObject);
    //this just creates a new GameObject and adds the script as a component

    //Set Transform
    phixelObject.transform.localScale = new Vector3(Constants.PIXEL_PER_METER, Constants.PIXEL_PER_METER, 1);
    phixelObject.transform.parent = chunk.transform;
    phixelObject.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(chunkPos.x - Constants.CHUNK_SIZE / 2, chunkPos.y - Constants.CHUNK_SIZE / 2, -chunkPos.z);

    //Add Sprite Renderer
    phixelObject.textureRenderer = phixelObject.AddComponent<SpriteRenderer>();

    //"create Texture_x" + phixelObject.dims.x.ToString() + "_y"+ phixelObject.dims.y.ToString()
    phixelObject.tex = new Texture2D(phixelObject.dims.x, phixelObject.dims.y, TextureFormat.RGBA32, -1, false, true);


    return phixelObject;
}

(I replaced the manual Profile.BeginSample() calls with comments for readability and removed parts that are not profiled)
In general it just seems really weird to me that the same Texture2D initialization for example takes 0.05ms 20 times in a row, before taking 40ms once or twice and then going back to 0.05ms.
As said, it can't be different texture sizes since these are the same most of the time.
I haven't completely ruled out GC issues either but I've changed classes to structs and reference type arrays to value type arrays to make it a lot easier to collect stuff.
So I hope anyone might know whats going on here,
or at least can give me some tips for finding the culprit.
Thanks in advance for any help! :)
Edit:

Theres only ever one chunk handled per frame
Chunks contain 1-3 of the created objects
For both screenshots I selected a chunk that only contains one object, so number of spawned objects shouldn't be the driving factor for the problem
I've been trying to replicate the problem outside of my project, but it doesn't seem to be as easy as just instantiating the same objects with dummy values. Which makes me think its got something to do with other processes slowing down the instantiation? But wouldn't they be somehow visible in the profiler?
weirdly enough the spikes show up categorized as "Editor Loop" when profiling in the editor

I tried deep profiling but the results are even more confusing


as you can see in the second pic, sometimes its the create texture call, sometimes its a string allocation and sometimes this RuntimeType.getFullName() causes the stutters. So I'm pretty sure some other thing going on in the background is just slowing down stuff in general. But how can I debug this?


perhaps you need to consider pooling?

@BugFinder you mean for the whole Objects? Might be a good Idea, I'll look into it thanks :)
Still doesn't explain why I'm having these issues in the first place. Or is there just some known unity thing that I don't know about, that makes it take ages once in a while when instantiating objects?

well pooling would mean reusing old created items, so not creating them persay, but just getting the next x unused, whats not clear from your code, is how many items are being made, is it always the same number? would this account for difference? [mcve]

Yea I used array pooling before, just didn't occur to me that I can do the same for the whole object.
And there is no difference in the amount of spawned objects in the screenshots, I added the info to my question though.

you should be able to do more granular checking on what specifically is slow, the profiler is an art

@BugFinder Alright, since I can't add manual profiler calls into the unity internal stuff I tried with deep profiling. This just showed that its all kinds of unity internal methods that are getting slowed down by whatevers happening here.
Also, when profiling in the editor, the same spikes show up categorized as Editor Loop, which seems weird to me.
Any Ideas on how to debug this further?

The profiler is an art.. if you click show it should show you all the parts it can break down, but it wont do line by line code, but it should tell you which methods you're calling that are slow.

PS editor spikes are editor fruityness, you need to profile outside the editor and only judge its performance outside the editor

Yes, thats exactly why I profiled outside of the editor, I was just saying that its weird that the same lag spikes get replaced by thos editor loop spkies. Also no idea what you mean with "the profiler is an art". If I click show, the only things I can do is print an example stack or see the same stuff in hierarchy view. Hierarchy view shows that the only process below what the timeline view shows is GC.alloc. But it also says that GC.alloc takes 0% of the time used.

must be a british phrase, saying something is an art, means its not straight forward and takes skills.. my skills are weak but ive not found i couldnt find enough of the answer to find it..

So I've got a smooth version running now but it took a lot of steps to get there.
The origin of the problem seemed to be a mix of just too many, too big texture.apply() calls, a still overloaded garbage collector and just in general a lot of spaghetti code that grew over the last months.
The answer is more complex and I went a bit more into detail here
but tl;dr:

Clean up your code, you know its been overdue for a while now
texture.apply() calls just tend to take a while so reduce usage of them
Use ComputeShaders and RenderTextures to reduce the number of objects from one per z-height layer per chunk to just one per chunk
Use SubUpdate ComputeBuffers and BeginWrite instead of SetData to move the expensive data copying work that texture.apply() did away from the main thread

